# Elasticsearch use index(analyzer) only

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I'm doing a query that should result with True/False, if there's at least one result for this query True else False, no extra data is needed.

Is there a way to query Elasticsearch so it will use only the index(analyzer) and return results by it? so it won't reach the real data blocks for the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query add "_source": "false". Like this:

```
{"_source": "false",
 "query": ...
}
```

This will only search for hits and won't access the stored fields for retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **size = 0** in query and check **hits.total > 0** for to check whether there is any result or not.

```
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        // your search
    }
}
```